# Is there a way to set JLabel text on create of Swing GUI window?

Tags: java, swing, static, jlabel

I'm making a form program using Swing GUI.

Now I need to set some text into a `JLabel` automatically, but I can't:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainForm");
    frame.setContentPane(new MainForm().jpanel1);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    // window position set
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int height = screenSize.height;
    int width = screenSize.width;
    frame.setLocation(width/2 - 100, height/2 - 100);

    lable_count.setText("please wait"); // this is not allow here because label is not static

    students = MongoDB.GetStudentFromMongo();
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Create a reference to your form. `MainForm form = new MainForm();` then add the panel. `frame.setContentPane(form.panel1);` and then you can reference the label. `form.label_count.setText("please wait");`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) As an aside: this `Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int height = screenSize.height;
    int width = screenSize.width;
    frame.setLocation(width/2 - 100, height/2 - 100);` can be shortened to this `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Your example at the time I right this comment does not show the declaration for `label_count` and has other syntax errors so that I cannot compile it myself. This makes it difficult to provide a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I got it from matt's commet

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        MainForm form = new MainForm(); // <<add this line
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainForm");
        frame.setContentPane(form.jpanel1); // <<change this
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("学生基本信息");
        // window position set
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int height = screenSize.height;
        int width = screenSize.width;
        frame.setLocation(width/2 - 100, height/2 - 100);

        form.lable_count.setText("please wait"); //<< then this will work
}
```